# Make a link that will open a new FULL SCREEN browser on iPad

Tags: ipad, browser, safari, hyperlink, fullscreen

Is there anyway that I can create a link that when clicked on an ipad, it will open in a new full screen window (no address bar/tabs/etc)?

Comment: Does it have to be the external browser? Otherwise you could just embed an UIWebView and configure it appropriately.

Comment: link will be opened from outlook, i don't know if there is a link attribute that will allow this for ipad... or if the webpage will have to make it full-screen once its opened somehow

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the only way that I am aware of to open a page in safari without the safari chrome(address bar/tabs/etc) is to add the `<meta>` tag following to the `<head>` element in the source.

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

Note that for this to work, the user must bookmark the page on their home screen. Apple provides a number of other meta tags as well that can add a 'native app' look and feel to the user's experience.  All of which can be found in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW3).

Comment: yea i have an "app" that runs from the home screen. but if a user registers on it and then clicks a link to confirm from their email, it will open in a new safari window with the tab/address bar.